# input range transition value

Tags: javascript, html, css, input

Can input range value use css transition for smooth movement? Something like this ?

```js
function test(){
document.querySelector('#a').value=70;
}
```

```css
#a{
  transition:all 1s;
}
```

```html
<input type="range" id="a" value="0" step="1" min="0" max="100">
<a href="#" onclick=test();return false;>test</a>
```

Comment: I wrote u something.hope u like

Answer (score 1):

Very hard to code with mobile also borring.I did my best shot .hope u like it

```js
function test(){
var v = 70;
var ev = 
document.getElementById("set-value").value;
 if (ev != ''){
   v = ev;
 }
 if (ev > 100){
   v = 100;
alert('up to 100 is allowed');
 }
  
document.querySelector('#a').value=v;
document.getElementById("show-range").innerHTML=v;
document.getElementById("for-a").style.width=v+"%";
 }
```

```css
#div {
  position:relative;
  width:100px;
  border: 1px solid lightblue;
  border-radius: 5px;
  height: 20px;
 }
#a {
  visibility: hidden;
 }
#for-a {
 position:absolute;
 top:0;
 left: 0;
 content:"";
 width:1px;
 height:20px;
 border-radius: 5px;
 background: lightblue;
 transition:all 1s ease-out;
}
```

```html
<div id="show-range"></div>
<div id="div">
<lable id="for-a" for="a">
<input type="range" id="a" value="0" step="1" min="0" max="100">
</label>
<a href="#" onclick=test();return false; >test</a> 
</div>
<br/>
<br/>
<input id="set-value" onKeyUp="test();" type="number">  any value up to 100
```